# is [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] thread safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, thread-safety, nsurlcredentialstorage

Is it safe to manipulate the object obtained from [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] from a non-main thread context (E.G. a serial dispatch queue?) when there's a web view control on the main thread?

Comment: Highly suggest you post this on Apple device forums, in networking. You will likely get a definitive answer not a guess.

Comment: Cheers, done: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/26735#26735

Comment: So the answer is yes by decree, maybe I'm showing my GNU heritage but I feel like "Citation Needed" is a thing here.

Comment: You can enter a bug report with apple and request that it gets added to the class documentation - all I can say is "good luck" with that. If it was an Apple person who responded, you could answer your own question with the URL above, and the statement that it was an Apple Engineer who said "Yes". If anyone contradicts that answer, you will get an email telling you the thread has been updated, and you could then update this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is yes.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/26735#26735